# Signal not declared in this scope/undefined reference to class::method

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator, qt5

I've been trying to sort out a custom signal in my Qt application, and I can't seem to get it to compile. Essentially I have a window with a slot to handle a button press (slotCalibrate()), and another slot to receive messages and output them to the screen via a QTextEdit (slotMessage()). Both of these functions work fine in isolation.

Here is Window.cpp, slotCalibrate() is currently sending prefabricated data to Output class. In the final design slotCalibrate() will activate a calibration process on some hardware, and the results of that will be the data sent to Output.cpp

```
#include "window.h"
#include "output.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QApplication>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(640, 480);

    calButton = new QPushButton("Calibrate", this);
    calButton->setGeometry(280, 20, 80, 30);
    calButton->setToolTip("Press to zero connected transducers.");

    connect(calButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotCalibrate()));

    quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit", this);
    quitButton->setGeometry(550, 440, 80, 30);

    connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));

    readout = new QTextEdit(this);
    readout->setReadOnly(1);
    readout->setPlainText("Testing, testing, 1, 2, 3.\n");
    readout->setGeometry(10, 70, 620, 360);
}

void Window::slotCalibrate()
{
    string sn[5] = {"1234", "2463", "7821", "5027", "5981"};
    Output *op = new Output();
    op->writeMessage(1, 5, sn);
    //I also tried the following with exactly the same result
    //Output op;
    //op.writeMessage(1, 5, sn);
}

void Window::slotMessage(string message)
{
    QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(message); //Convert from string to QString
    readout->append(qstr);                          //Print message to screen
}
```

I'm trying to get the button press to call the constructor of output.cpp, and then call the function writeMessage to construct and emit a message to slotMessage in window.cpp

```
#include "output.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

Output::Output(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    connect (this, SIGNAL(sendMessage(string)), parentWidget(), SLOT(slotMessage(string)));
}

//void sendMessage(string)
//{

//}

void writeMessage(int cat, int count, string sn[])
{
    int i;
    stringstream ss;
    switch (cat)
    {
        case 1 : //Case where calibration of one or more nodes was successful
            ss << count << " transducers were successfully calibrated.\n Their serial numbers are:";
            for (i=0; i<cat; i++)
            {
                ss << "\n" << sn[i];
            }
            break;
        case 2:  //Case where calibration of one or more nodes failed
            ss << "One or more transducers failed to calibrate.";
            break;
        case 3:  //Case where no config file is found
            ss << "WARNING! Could not find 'params.config'. The default values will be used for calibration.";
                  break;
    }
    emit sendMessage(ss.str());
}
```

Unfortunately, with the code exactly like this, the compiler shouts at me. It says:
`'sendMessage' was not declared in this scope`

I have declared `sendMessage` in the header file as a signal, and I was under the impression signals didn't need to be implemented in code.

Nevertheless, I decided to try implementing an empty function called `sendMessage`. This got rid of the compiler error, but introduced another error. When calling `op.writeMessage()` in window.cpp, I get the error:
 "undefined reference to `Output::writeMessage(int, int, std::string*)'"

I have also tried calling `writeMessage` inside the Output constructor, and I get the same error.

I am thoroughly lost, and have been working on this issue for a couple of days now, so any help would be immensely appreciated.

For completeness here are the header files window.h and output.h respectively:

window.h

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H
#define WINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <string>

class QPushButton;
class QTextEdit;
class Window : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Window(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QTextEdit *readout;
private:
    QPushButton *calButton;
    QPushButton *quitButton;

signals:

public slots:
    void slotCalibrate();

private slots:
    void slotMessage(std::string);
};

#endif // WINDOW_H
```

output.h

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_H
#define OUTPUT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QObject>
#include <string>

class Output : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Output(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void writeMessage(int, int, std::string[]);
signals:
    void sendMessage(std::string);
public slots:

};

#endif // OUTPUT_H
```

Comment: in you output.cpp you must pre-append Output:: for the writeMessage method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this does not work. You defined the writeMessage() function but you defined it as a global function. You must prepend an "Output::" to the definition.